# NetSuite - Suitescript 1.0

Tags: suitescript1.0

how to set fields on customer record in before Load event , on before submit event and on after submit event? i am trying to create a message record and check this code.

```
if (type == 'create')
    {
        var custRecord = nlapiGetNewRecord();
        
        if(custRecord.getFieldValue('salesrep') != null)
        {
            var message = nlapiCreateRecord("message");
            
            message.setFieldValue('entity');
            
            message.setFieldValue('message');
            
            custRecord.getFieldValue('salesrep');
            
            var today = new Date();
            var tomorrow = nlapiAddDays(today, 1);
            message.setFieldValue('startdate', nlapiDateToString(tomorrow));
            
            message.setFieldValue('message',custRecord.getFieldValue('message'));
            
            
            try
            {
                var callId = nlapiSubmitRecord(message, true);
                nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'message record created successfully', 'ID = ' + messageId);
            }
            catch (e)
            {
                nlapiLogExecution('ERROR', e.getcode(), e.getDetails());
            }
        }
        
    }
```

why don't i get the message field in my customer record?

Answer (score 0):

I don't realy understand what you want to do :). you set fields with empty values....  anyway to create a messege in NS1.0. you need this :

```
var message = nlapiCreateRecord("message");

/** mandatory fields */
message.setFieldValue('subject', "message title");
message.setFieldValue('message', "message body");
/** /mandatory fields */

/** attach the msg to a record, transaction */

/** customers, prospects, etc */
message.setFieldValue('entity', "entityInternalID"); 

/** sales orders, invoices, etc */
message.setFieldValue('transaction', "transactionInternalID");

/** cases */
message.setFieldValue('activity', "caseInternalId");

/** /attach the msg to a record, transaction */

/** save the msg */
var msgId = nlapiSubmitRecord(message, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let us know what kind of script you are creating? Is it a userevent or client script? Anyway, since you have mentioned that you want it to run in 3 specific context I'm assuming it is a userevent script.
I highly discouraged using 1.0 if you're developing a Netsuite script. It will be unsupported soon and will become obsolete. Here's a detailed example on how to create userevent script
https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/51660/kw/Creating%20a%20user%20event%20script

Comment: Hi james, welcome to SO :) it's a good habit to write explicitly how to do some things and just then add reference link. This way, if link will ever become inactive in the future, someone can always read what you have suggested.

Comment: No worries. I'll take note of that. I'm new here.